# Error while running my code in C# after applying a decimal format

Tags: c#, tostring

I was creating a code for the movement of my character (for my assignment) and wanted to find out the distance and angle between the 1st point and 2nd point. I used `Math` class and `ToString` method to get desired results. But after running the code (using visual studio) I got this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.
>      at System.Number.FormatSingle(Single value, String format, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at System.Single.ToString(String format)
>      at PeerGradedAssignment1.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\RIT\new vs coursera c3 progjects\PeerGradedAssignment1\PeerGradedAssignment1\Program.cs:line 58
>   .

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PeerGradedAssignment1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For deciding the approach of point 1 to point 2
    /// </summary>

    class Program
    {   /// <summary>
        /// Taking values of points     
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command-line args</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Asking for values(X,Y) of point1 and point

            Console.Write("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine(". In this aplication I will calculate" +
                          "the distance between two pints and the amgle between them.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the X value for the 1st point: ");
            float pointX1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the Y value for the 1st point: ");
            float pointY1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the X value for the 2nd point: ");
            float pointX2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the Y value for the 2nd point: ");
            float pointY2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Claculating the distance between point1 and point2

            float deltaX = pointX2 - pointX1;
            float deltaY = pointY2 - pointY1;
            // dist12 , 12 stands for 1-2
            float squaredist12 = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
            float dist12 = (float)Math.Sqrt(squaredist12);
            Console.WriteLine("Distance between point and point 2:" + " " + dist12);

            // Calculating the angle between them

            float radians = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaX,deltaY);

           // Converting radians to angles

            float degrees = (float)radians * (180 / (float)Math.PI);
            Console.WriteLine(degrees);
            Console.WriteLine(dist12.ToString("D3"));
        } 
    }
}
```

[This is the image for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4zlB.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. It looks like it could easily be two lines in a `Main` method: `float value = 123.45f; Console.WriteLine(dist.ToString("D3"));`

Comment: So you read the error message that said your format specifier was not valid. You then presumably googled the documentation and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings - where was the problem after this?

Comment: You can't directly convert a float to an integer format using "D3".  Try ((int)dist12).ToString("D3")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format D3 can't be used with floats. You need to use n3

e.g

```
Console.WriteLine(dist12.ToString("n3"));
```

Comment: I guess that means double is a float. this fixed my problem.